# Assign charracters/value to uint8_t array

Tags: c, arrays, function, char, uint8t

Have a look at the code below:

```
/* NDEF messages TEXT */
const uint8_t text1[] = "This is message No1";
```

This is used to set a NDEF message. Is it possible to write an array with a function instead of defining the array like above?

I want to make a function which reads a value from the adc of the microcontroller and write that value to a NDEF message which will be sent via NFC to an Android Device.

Is it possible to initialize an uint8_t array with a function, something like below?

```
uint8_t text[] = someFunction();
```

It is probably not possible to keep this a const uint. But that doesn't matter beacuse the array will only change before the message is send, so it won't change unexpected or something like that.

Comment: At the very least you'll need to provide a size for the array, since the compiler won't have any way to derive it.

Comment: You could have `uint8_t *text;` and then in the code, `text = someFunction();` But for it to work they way you're describing, the initializer would need to be known at compile time.

Comment: Thank you mbratch. I should probably assign the array in a function.